# Why do we need the strong interaction if we have Yukawa's meson theory?

Tags: quantum-chromodynamics, quarks, strong-force, mesons, gluons

How is Yukawa's theory of mesons different from the standard model's strong interaction? I mean if Yukawa's theory is complete then why do we need quarks and gluons?

Comment: One does not *need* any interaction. The interactions are just there and one introduces suitable formalisms to describe them. In the case at hand, the strong interaction is by matter of fact present in the universe and is well described by QFT as a gauge theory on a $\textrm{SU}(3)$ gauge bundle. If you then ask why the description is so, then this is another kind of question.

Comment: @gen with respect, isn't it obvious that the OP wants to know why observed strong interactions can't be described by meson theory?

Comment: Right, I should have been more precise: Yukawa theory is an effective theory that properly works in some particular cases (but doesn't in some other); nowadays the description that works properly in all the cases that we have experimentally seen is the SM strong interaction, thus we accept the latter to be more general than the former.

Answer (score 5):

The [Yukawa meson theory](http://www.physics.princeton.edu/~kirkmcd/examples/EP/brown_centaurus_25_71_81.pdf) was a theory developed to describe the force between protons and neutrons in the nucleus. It works very well at low energies but fails completely at energies high enough that the internal structure of the hadrons becomes important.

The strong force, or more precisely [quantum chromodynamics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_chromodynamics), describes the interactions between quarks, so it describes the internal structure of hadrons in a way that the Yukawa theory cannot. At low energies the strong force predicts the same force between hadrons as the Yukawa theory.